# Transform3d did not work for firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions

Transform 3d was working fine in last version of firefox but in its new updated version 52.0.1 (32-bit), it did not work. CSS code is below

When menu close:

```
.c-menu {
     transform: translate3d(268px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(268px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(268px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

When menu open (from right):

```
#sidebar.toggled {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

translate3d not working in latest Firefox version do this it will fix your issue

```
.c-menu {
    right: -268px
}

#sidebar.toggled {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0px
}
```